# Linux distro with no kernel update

Tags: kernel, updates

What are the Linux distributions which give no kernel updates? I know 2. Linux Mint and Manjaro. Which other Linux distributions (deb preferable)give no Linux kernel update after installation?

Comment: So you'd rather stay with all the security holes discovered after the release? All Debian-based distros allow blocking updates for particular packages, that's built into Apt.

Comment: I am a desktop user. I don't care about security holes. I am OK with it. Also I use proprietary drivers and I cannot update kernel.

Comment: besides, all the nvidia drivers and most other proprietary drivers are available through apt-get and the software center on ubuntu because ubuntu isn't all that concerned with what is and what isn't proprietary or non-free.

Comment: I have AMD GPU. I'll try dkms.

Comment: actually you don't need dkms,  just go to the software center, click edit then go to software sources and click on the additional drivers tab and then select the fglrx driver that shows "tested"

Comment: Although dkms might work with that I've never used it though. I believe you will have to rebuild the driver after installing dkms if you do decide to go that route.

Comment: dkms is already installed and latest. So I think I should only try installing from software centre then.

Answer (score 2):

Mint and Manjaro do give kernel updates, why did you think that? And why would someone want that? You could build your own Linux OS with tutorials like Linux From Scratch. Since everything is compiled from source and there is no updating system by default, the kernel won't be automatically updated. By the way you should ask questions like this (not Ubuntu-specific) in Unix&Linux.

Comment: You can chose if you want to get newer kernel updates in Manjaro. Also I don't see any kernel updates yet in Mint.

Comment: That doesn't mean these systems are "kernel updates free", since the upgrades are actually available. And since Mint (17) is based in Ubuntu 14.04, a Long Term Support version, it gets quite few upgrades because its target is stability. But that does NOT mean it doesn't get kernel upgrades.

Comment: manjaro should have almost the most update kernels out of all three mentioned